# Prove $\alpha \leq \beta \Rightarrow \alpha^{\gamma} \leq \beta^{\gamma}$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma $ ordinal numbers . Prove $\alpha \leq \beta \Rightarrow \alpha^{\gamma} \leq \beta^{\gamma}$.

**Attempt** Induction under $\gamma$.

If $\gamma=0 \Rightarrow \alpha^{0} = 1 = \beta^{0}$ [but what happens if $\alpha = 0$ or $\beta =0$]

If $\exists \delta$ ordinal number such that $\delta +1= \gamma \Rightarrow \alpha^{\gamma}=\alpha^{\delta+1}= \alpha^{\delta}* \alpha \leq \beta^{\delta}*\alpha \leq \beta^{\delta}*\beta= \beta^{\delta+1}= \beta^{\gamma}$

If $\gamma \neq 0$ is a limit ordinal $\Rightarrow \forall \delta < \gamma, \alpha^{\delta} \leq \beta^{\delta} \Rightarrow \alpha^{\gamma}= \mbox{sup }\{\alpha^{\delta}: \delta < \gamma\} \leq \mbox{sup }\{\beta^{\delta}: \delta < \gamma\}= \beta^{\gamma}$

By principle of transfinite induction, $\forall \alpha, \beta, \gamma \mbox{ with } \alpha \leq \beta \Rightarrow \alpha^{\gamma} \leq \beta^{\gamma}$

Could you check, if my prove is correct?

Comment: For the record, in ordinal arithmetic $0^0=1$.

Comment: Can I define $0^{0}=1$?

Comment: The definition of ordinal exponentiation *implies* that $0^0=1$; you don't have to define it separately or do an ad hoc definition. That's what it is. (Same with cardinality, since $0^0$ is the cardinal of the set of functions from the empty set to the empty set, which is $1$).

Comment: Then, $\forall \beta \mbox{ limit ordinal, }0^{\beta}=0?$

Comment: Can we obtain $\alpha^\delta\cdot\alpha\le\beta^\delta\cdot\alpha$ just from $\alpha\leq\beta$? I have found a source for left-monotonicity of ordinal exponentiation but not right-monotonicity.